# INSERT data from spark dataframe to a table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Scala Notebook on Databricks. I need to perform an INSERT of data from a dataframe to a table in SQL server. If the data already exist, no need modify or insert - only insert data that do not exist.

I tried the methods specified here https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#write-data-to-jdbc, however, they don't address my usecase. The SaveMode.Append creates duplicate entries of the data, SaveMode.Overwrite replaces the existing data (table), SaveMode.Ignore does not add any new data if the table already exists.

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(url=dbUrl, table=table_name, dbConnectionProperties)

How can I do an INSERT of new data only to the database?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: would you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75566275

Answer (score 3):

Assume your current dataframe is df1.

You should read the existing data in the SQL table into another dataframe (df2).
Then use subtract (or subtractByKey): http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=subtract

```
val dfFinal = df1.subtract(df2)
```

dfFinal will contain the remaining records to insert.

Comment: Thanks! This approach will require bringing in large amount of data (500M+ per job) in to Databricks. Is it recommended to have the duplicate check and INSERT done in spark rather than in SQL? Does it typically provide better performance from your experience? I will test it, but just wondering if you already experimented this.

Comment: Yeah that can be an issue. Ideally you wouldn't load the whole 500m. Instead select records from say the past 24 hours where you may have duplicates. If that is not possible another option is to load df1 into a staging table and then execute a SQL statement to load the new records using a join.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: - It's a workaround. Not a full proof solution.

There can be a workaround for this issue. 
You need to maintain an auto-increment key/primary key in the SQL server table. And the source data too should have this key in the data before an insert.

The following conditions can arise:

```
New Primary key == Old Primary key -> job will fail with constraints exception.
New Primary key != Old Primary key -> insert successfully.
```

The insert into table failure can be handled at the program level.

Comment: Not really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid bringing in the entire set to do a comparison you could put a Unique Index on the SQL Table and use the option to Ignore Duplicates.

[MS Document: Create Unique Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE ] [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] INDEX index_name
    ON <object> ( column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ] )
    [ INCLUDE ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]
    [ WHERE <filter_predicate> ]
    [ WITH ( <relational_index_option> [ ,...n ] ) ]
    [ ON { partition_scheme_name ( column_name )
         | filegroup_name
         | default
         }
    ]
    [ FILESTREAM_ON { filestream_filegroup_name | partition_scheme_name | "NULL" } ]

[ ; ]

<object> ::=
{ database_name.schema_name.table_or_view_name | schema_name.table_or_view_name | table_or_view_name }

<relational_index_option> ::=
{
  | IGNORE_DUP_KEY = { ON | OFF }
}
```