# Spark: Missing data after having heartbeat error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Python program that run on the Spark cluster with four workers.It processes a huge Oracle table with about 15 Millions records. After checking the result, I found that about 6 Millions records have not been inserted. My write function is like following:

```
df.write.format('jdbc').options(
        url=spark_write_url,
        driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
        dbtable=dest_table_name,
        user=username,
        password=password).mode('append') \
        .save()
```

I checked the Master:

```
14:20:22 INFO Master: Telling app of lost executor: 1
14:20:22 INFO Master: Telling app of lost worker: worker-20230212103757-1.1.1.1-44269
14:20:22 WARN Master: Removing worker-20230212103834-1.1.1.3-36115 because we got no heartbeat in 60 seconds
14:20:22 INFO Master: Removing worker worker-20230212103834-1.1.1.3-36115 on 1.1.1.3:36115
14:20:22 INFO Master: Telling app of lost executor: 3
14:20:22 INFO Master: Telling app of lost worker: worker-20230212103834-1.1.1.3-36115
```

Also, I check worker log:

```
 14:19:52 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]. 
 This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:996)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$heartbeater$1(Executor.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$Lambda$356/1672492577.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)
at org.apache.spark.Heartbeater$$anon$1.run(Heartbeater.scala:46)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:293)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
... 14 more
```

My output table has primary key on ***ID*** which is unique for sure. But, when I check my log, see this error:

```
14:20:53,547 - INFO - functions - Dest Table : trx, Exception in Write Spark :An error occurred while calling o2192.save.
```

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 48 in stage 274.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 48.3 in stage 274.0 (TID 10159) (1.1.1.4 executor 0): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ID_PK) violated.

I have three questions, would you please guide me?

*First*, in Spark Standalone how data are managed when worker node is lost?

*Second*, how Spark insert data? Does it insert data Bulk by Bulk? For example, when Spark is inserting one Bulk and the Bulk has error like, `unique constraint violated`,  Spark ignore the Bulk and does not insert it?

*Three*, how can be sure that Spark program finish its work correctly without checking the result manually?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some code? it looks like the data you are trying to insert has duplicate ids which could abort the bulk insert

Comment: @IslamElbanna, yeah you're right. It has duplicate ids. Because,after losting node 2; node 1 try to insert batch of data which was belong to node 2 and some ids has been inserted by node 2 and then node 1 try to insert them; so, it receive ```unique constraint violated``` and the whole batch dismissed.

Comment: I think then you can try `.mode('ignore')` so it can ignore if the data were inserted before https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc