# Inserting every records of Spark Dataframe to the Oracle table which is not Exist

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark Program. At the end of it, I must insert the Spark Dataframe to the Oracle table and be sure that records are inserted when they are not exist. I have already define primary key on the table; but sometimes it does not help. As I explain the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75566275).

So, I use ***ignore mode*** in the Spark `write` method like this:

```
 df.write.mode('ignore').format('jdbc').options(
        url=spark_write_url,
        driver='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
        dbtable=dest_table_name,
        user=username,
        password=password) \
        .save()
```

As [this link](https://dbmstutorials.com/pyspark/spark-dataframe-write-modes.html) explains, when ***ignore*** mode is used then write operation will ignore current write operation if data / table already exists without throwing error or exception. If data/table does not exists then write operation with ignore mode will behave normally.
But when I run the program and the table is empty, not any data are inserted to it.

Would you please any one guide me how to solve the problem and what is wrong with the code?

Any help is really appreciated.